# removing border of a panel in flex

Tags: apache-flex, panel

Is there a way to remove the left+right+bottom border of a mx:Panel?

basically I want to have the right UI instead of the left one ( check the screenshot )

[image]

I know that the default spark Panel is able to do so, but I just need to use Flex 3.

Here is what I tried already :

- padding (seems only changing the children)
- borderStyle = none is removing the color of the header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the following styles for your panel:

```
borderThicknessLeft: 0;
borderThicknessTop: 0;
borderThicknessBottom: 0;
borderThicknessRight: 0;
```

There's quite useful [Flex Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html#) when you stucked with styles.

Comment: +1 for the "Flex Style Explorer". Never know that Flex has that URL. Will check your answer tmr. Thanks.

Comment: "Flex Style Explorer" is missing from Flex site. Here is an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16179450/552669