# Where is the Adobe Flex Style explorer Sample app

Tags: apache-flex, styles, explorer

I have did not checked it since a while, but now I need to maintain some old flex 2/3 code (I need to update some colors and styles).

The problem  is that I did had the Flex 2 Style Explorer showcase app from Adobe bookmarked, but not I cannot reach it any more.

Can someone help and provide a valid link, please.

Old link was http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.html#/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: AFAIK it's in the process of being donated to Apache Flex. Here's a discussion on the topic on the dev list: http://markmail.org/message/fyudrdcfe7qanzrj#query:+page:1+mid:fyudrdcfe7qanzrj+state:results

Comment: thanks for the comment, I have also posted this question to adobe forums. Maybe they can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the source for the Flex 2 style Explorer, i downloaded once upon a time when its is active. check this out.

[Flex2StyleExplorer Source Zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48296625/FlexExplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.zip)

Also found the Flex 3 style Explorer in web archieves.

[Web archieve for Flex 3 Style explorer](http://web.archive.org/web/20120516031743/http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html)

[Flex 3 Component Explorer](http://web.archive.org/web/20120918204503/http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/componentexplorer/explorer.html)

[Flex 2 PrimitiveExplorer](http://www.flexibleexperiments.com/Flex/PrimitiveExplorer/Flex2PrimitiveExplorer.html)

Hope this will help you